# Change WooCommerce PayPal Built-in Default Order Status

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

I want to change the default status the built in PayPal gateway in WooCommerce . Currently, when a new order is created, it's updating to 'processing'. I want to change it but I can't see anywhere to change it, not in the WooCommerce -> Payments settings and not in the code (probably I just missed it).

Does anyone knows where it is?

Thanks.

Comment: please check the link i hope solve your problem : https://www.angelleye.com/automatically-update-woocommerce-order-status-when-paypal-payment-completes/

Comment: As I understands it talks about the PayPal integration. I am using the WooCommerce Built-in PayPal gateway, will it still work?

Comment: not clear your question for me please explain to me  i help you

Comment: I am using the PayPal gateway that comes with WooCommerce. Apparently it's called PayPal Standard.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Currently, when an order is created through the PayPal gateway, the new order status will be `processing`. I want to change it so it will be set to a custom status I have created.

Comment: i send code for you please check and this code add your functions.php file

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'changing_order_status_before_payment', 10, 3 );
function changing_order_status_before_payment( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $order->update_status( 'pending' );
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87448/discussion-between-vikrant-zilpe-and-omer).

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function change_order_status( $order_id ){
     if( ! $order_id ) return;
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     if( $order->get_status() == 'processing' )
     $order->update_status( 'pending' );
}
```

Comment: I tried to look for the function which changes the order status in order to edit it but did not find it... hence the question, how can I make the PayPal gateway change the order status to a custom status instead of 'processing'?